# Updating a column in sql with variable value

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to update a table column by using a variable that contains name of the column instead of writing the column name. How to correctly can I write the query? I've tried

```
UPDATE Room 
SET ['"+Time+"']=0 
where Day='"+Day+"'
```

this query is showing error saying

> invalid column name

although it perfectly matches the column name.

Comment: _this query is showing a syntax error_ What error?

Comment: I'd love to know what you were trying to do with all the `' " + `

Comment: Print out the complete final query string and inspect whether it makes sense. The quote characters and spaces inside the `[]` characters for quoting the column name look highly suspect to me. Of course, the whole idea looks suspect to me, since it smells strongly of data having been mis-modelled as *metadata*, i.e. embedded in column names

Comment: i am trying to use the value of time to update the coulmn  instead of directly writing the column name of the table.

Answer (score 1):

you, probably, are looking for a syntax like this:

```
  string sql = 
     $@"UPDATE Room
           SET [{Time}] = 0 -- Time contains field's name no need in '...'
         WHERE [Day] = '{Day}'";
```

However, *hardcoding* - `...'{Day}'...` is a *bad practice*, parametrizing is the *right way*:

```
  string sql = 
     $@"UPDATE Room
           SET [{Time}] = 0
         WHERE [Day] = @prm_Day";

  // Providing that you use MS SQL - SqlCommand
  using (SqlCommand q = new SqlCommand(sql, MyConnection)) {
    //TODO: Check the actual RDMBS type - is it SqlDbType.DateTime? 
    q.Parameters.Add("@prm_Day", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Day;

    q.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

**Edit**: Old C# versions don't support *string interpolation* (`$` before a string, see comments below), the alternative is *formatting*:

```
  string sql = string.Format(
     @"UPDATE Room
          SET [{0}] = 0 -- Time contains field's name no need in '...'
        WHERE [Day] = '{1}'", Time, Day);
```

and

```
  string sql = string.Format(
      @"UPDATE Room
           SET [{0}] = 0
         WHERE [Day] = @prm_Day", Time);
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @marc_s: Thank you! Quite argee. I've edited my premature answer

Comment: I probably couldn't explain my problem . I am trying to use a variable  which contains the column name to update it  instead of directly writing the column.is it possible?

Comment: @Sadia Labonno: yes, your problem is quite clear: `Time` contains the *field's name* (e.g. `MyField`). In my answer I've used *string interpolation* to insert `Time` value into a string : `$@"...{Time}..."` will result as `"...MyField..."`. Your problem is in *apostrophes* - we don't enclose *field names* in them

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko Thank you i got it but can you please explain  why my query is not working though it worked perfectly while doing java project.

Comment: @Sadia Labonno: Java and C# are quite different in string processing (formatting, string interpolation etc.); they use different dirivers as well: JDBC and .Net one. Please, check query texts right before execution (put a break point) in Java project. Do you have apostrophes enclosing the field name?

Comment: yes i have used apostrophes to enclose the field name.I tried to use your code but then again showing error like'Unexpected $ sign' in this line - $@"UPDATE Room
           SET [{Time}] = 0
         WHERE [Day] = @prm_Day";

Comment: @Sadia Labonno: It seems, that you use an old C# version (without *string interpolation*), let's solve it with *formatting*